# in jquery, making a selector that does select everything except one elemtnt

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I make a selector that chooses, for example, everything in the 'html', except element "#element-dont-choose-me'

I was looking at things like:

```
$("div > ul a")
```

But I know that's way off..

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':not(#element-dont-choose-me)')
```

Going out on a limb here and omitting the `*` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("*:not(#element-dont-choose-me)");
```

The `*` asterisk (or omission of it) is going to select ***everything*** that doesn't fit the selector though, so be careful how you use it.

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: A little nit, the `*` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `:not()` selector. This should probably work:

```
jQuery('html *:not(#element-dont-choose-me)');
```

but you should try on your own :)